# Tailwind CSS и Live Server с VS Code не обновляет HTML-классы при использовании флага --jit

Tags: visual-studio-code, tailwindcss, jit

Решил попробовать в Tailwind CSS JIT-mode. Запускаю с флагами `-o tailwind.css --jit --purge index.html -w`. Компилируется без ошибок. Слежка включается. Начинаю прописывать классы в index.html,  Live Server обновляет браузер (страница перезагружается), в CSS файле стили обновляются, но в браузере изменения не применяются. В инспекторе браузера видно, что в HTML не обновляются классы. Только когда вручную F5 обновляешь страницу, тогда классы обновляются. 
Если запустить компиляцию без флага `--jit`, то все работает. и `--purge` и `--watch` свою работу делаю и в браузере все классы обновляются и все работает как надо. Проблема наблюдается в разных браузерах и в режиме инкогнито 
Вот что еще делал: ставил чистый VS Code и только один плагин Live Server - тоже не работает; ставил другой Live Server от Tapio https://github.com/tapio/live-server - такая же проблема.
Пожалуйста, друзья, помогите, может кто знает как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась установкой другого сервера [Five Server (Live Server)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yandeu.five-server). Решение мне предложили в дискуссии официального github репозитория Tailwind CSS